# Query com ForEach e Subquery Node JS e MSSQL

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Estou com um problema que não achei solução ainda, tenho um select em uma procedure, que faço um forEach no resultado, dentro desse forEach faço outro select em outra procedure utilizando os Ids conforme código abaixo.

Funciona o problema é que na hora de fazer o bulk no mongo db por algum motivo a function done() esta chamando o bulk mais de uma vez, em algum momento o done() esta sendo chamado mais de uma vez.

```html
var consultaSQL = function(){

  console.time('sql');
  sequelize.query('PRS_MONGO_PRODUTO;', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(function(result){
    console.log(result.length);
    console.timeEnd('sql');

    done = _.after(result.length, function () {
      if(result.length > 0) {
        var i = 1;
        var bulk = Detalhe.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        console.time('bulk');
        result.forEach(function(p){
          bulk.find({ produtoId: p.produtoId, clienteId: p.clienteId }).upsert().replaceOne(p);
        });
        console.timeEnd('bulk');

        console.log('Quantidade Exec: ' + result.length);
        console.time('exec');

        bulk.execute(function (err, result) {
          if(err) console.error(err);
          console.timeEnd('exec');
          console.log('##################### Inicia em 5 Segundos! #####################');
          var teste =  setTimeout(function () {
            consultaSQL();
          }, 5000);
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log('##################### Sem registros! #####################');
        setTimeout(function () {
          consultaSQL();
        }, 30000);
      }
    });
    if(result.length == 0) done();
    result.forEach(function(p){
      p.skus = [];
      sequelize.query('PRS_PESQ_PRODUTO_INDEXACAO_MONGO ' + p.clienteId + ', ' + p.produtoId, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(function(resultA){
        done2 = _.after(resultA.length, function () {
          done();
        });

        if(resultA.length == 0) done2();

        resultA.forEach(function(s){
          sequelize.query('select caminho as imagem from produtoSkuImagem where produtoSkuId = ' + s.produtoSkuId, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(function(resultB){

            done3 = _.after(resultB.length, function () {
              done2();
            });
            s.imagens = [];
            s.imagens.push(resultB)
            p.skus.push(s);
            done3();
          });

        });

      });
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
    process.exit();
  });
}
```

O resultado que ele tem que gerar é esse abaixo:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("573b202f6d16e35c707c3119"),
"clienteId" : 1,
"produtoId" : 3948,
"parceiroId" : 1,
"codigoProduto" : "2014526",
"nome" : "Armário Blumenau Branco - Politorno",
"descricao" : "Armário para Forno Microondas, com duas portas.Fabricado em chapas de 15mm. Limpeza do móvel deve ser feita com um pano umedecido com água.",
"codigoMarca" : 3150,
"marca" : "Politorno",
"produtoSkuId" : 4424,
"peso" : 23250,
"altura" : 11,
"comprimento" : 109,
"estoque" : 1,
"preco" : 185.31,
"precoDe" : 285,
"pontos" : 195,
"parcelamento" : 1,
"imagem" : "https://static.wmobjects.com.br/imgres/arquivos/ids/2509026",
"ativo" : 1,
"dataCadastro" : ISODate("2016-03-21T11:10:53.620Z"),
"dataAtualizacao" : ISODate("2016-05-17T10:29:27.590Z"),
"skus" : [ 
    {
        "clienteId" : 1,
        "produtoId" : 3948,
        "parceiroId" : 1,
        "codigoProduto" : "2014526",
        "nome" : "Armário Blumenau Branco - Politorno",
        "descricao" : "Armário para Forno Microondas, com duas portas.Fabricado em chapas de 15mm. Limpeza do móvel deve ser feita com um pano umedecido com água.",
        "codigoMarca" : 3150,
        "marca" : "Politorno",
        "produtoSkuId" : 4424,
        "peso" : 23250,
        "altura" : 11,
        "comprimento" : 109,
        "estoque" : 1,
        "preco" : 185.31,
        "precoDe" : 285,
        "pontos" : 195,
        "parcelamento" : 1,
        "imagem" : "https://static.wmobjects.com.br/imgres/arquivos/ids/2509026",
        "ativo" : 1,
        "dataCadastro" : ISODate("2016-03-21T11:10:53.620Z"),
        "dataAtualizacao" : ISODate("2016-05-17T10:29:27.590Z"),
        "imagens" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "imagem" : "https://static.wmobjects.com.br/imgres/arquivos/ids/2514797"
                }, 
                {
                    "imagem" : "https://static.wmobjects.com.br/imgres/arquivos/ids/2514804"
                }, 
                {
                    "imagem" : "https://static.wmobjects.com.br/imgres/arquivos/ids/2514811"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Esse código funciono o problema é que ele chama o bulk mais de uma vez sendo assim ele inseri mais de uma vez, então o resultado fica demorado. Preciso que o done() seja chamado somente uma vez e do modo certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é que você transforme sua query em apenas uma, trazendo todos os produtos e relacionando já com todos os skus e imagens. Fica muito mais performático do que fazer outras queries dentro de um loop.
Os registros vindo duplicados vc trata isso no código.
Fiz uma função de exemplo pra facilitar:

```js
// Esse é o resultado da sua query com todos os joins
var resultset = [
 {prod: 1, prod_nome: 'prod_1', sku: 51, sku_nome: 'a', img: '1.jpg'},
 {prod: 1, prod_nome: 'prod_1', sku: 51, sku_nome: 'a', img: '2.jpg'},
 {prod: 1, prod_nome: 'prod_1', sku: 51, sku_nome: 'a', img: '3.jpg'},
 {prod: 1, prod_nome: 'prod_1', sku: 52, sku_nome: 'b', img: '1.gif'},
 {prod: 1, prod_nome: 'prod_1', sku: 52, sku_nome: 'b', img: '2.gif'},
 {prod: 1, prod_nome: 'prod_1', sku: 52, sku_nome: 'b', img: '3.gif'},
 {prod: 2, prod_nome: 'prod_2', sku: 53, sku_nome: 'c', img: 'c1.jpg'},
 {prod: 2, prod_nome: 'prod_2', sku: 53, sku_nome: 'c', img: 'c2.jpg'},
 {prod: 2, prod_nome: 'prod_2', sku: 54, sku_nome: 'd', img: 'd.jpg'}
];

function Resultset(rs){
 var o = this;
 o.reader = rs;
 o.idx = -1;
 o.len = rs.length;
 o.current = null;
 o.fieldKeys = {}
 o.lastFKeyIteration = null;
 o.end = false;
}
Resultset.prototype.get = function(field) {
 return this.current[field];    
}
Resultset.prototype.next = function(fieldKey) {
 var o = this;
 var rs = o.reader;
 fieldKey = fieldKey || null;
 var nextFK = fieldKey != o.lastFKeyIteration && o.lastFKeyIteration != null;
 if(!nextFK)
  o.idx++;
    
 o.lastFKeyIteration = fieldKey;
 if(fieldKey != null && typeof o.fieldKeys[fieldKey] == 'undefined')
    o.fieldKeys[fieldKey] = null;
    
 if(!o.end){
  if((fieldKey != null && nextFK) || o.idx < o.len) {
   if(fieldKey != null) {
    for(var fk in o.fieldKeys) {
     var _v = rs[o.idx][fk];
     if(_v != o.fieldKeys[fk] && fk != fieldKey)
      return false;

     if(fk == fieldKey) {
      o.fieldKeys[fieldKey] = _v;
      break;
     }
    }
   }
   
   o.current = rs[o.idx];
   return true;
  }
  o.end = true;
  return false;
 }
 return false;
}




// Para utilizar ficaria algo do tipo:
var rs = new Resultset(resultset);

var data = [];
if(rs.next('prod')){
  do{
    var prod = {
      id: rs.get('prod'),
      nome: rs.get('prod_nome'),
    };
    var skus = []; 
    while(rs.next('sku')){
      var sku = {
        id: rs.get('sku'),
        nome: rs.get('sku_nome')
      };
      var imgs = [];
      while(rs.next('img')){
        imgs.push(
          rs.get('img')
        );
      }
      sku.imagens = imgs;
      skus.push(sku);
    }
    prod.skus = skus;
    data.push(prod);
  }
  while(rs.next('prod'));

  console.log(data);
}
else{
  console.log('Nenhum registro');
}
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, agora vou implementar mais alguns campos que tenho e já era. TKS!